# My fulltext index option in sqlserver2008 is greyed out?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

My fulltext index option in sqlserver2008 is greyed out?

Is it a seperate install?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the Full-Text indexing option is greyed out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413809/why-the-full-text-indexing-option-is-greyed-out)

Answer (score 13):

You can enable it by executing [sp_fulltext_database](http://crazzycoding.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-server-why-full-text-indexing.html) command.

Comment: Thanks Ashish!  When migrating older DBs over to 2008 I was unable to work with full-text until setting the property w/ this SP

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the Full Text Search feature was installed.  Run the following query against your database:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

A result of '0' (Zero) means Full Text search is **not** installed on the server.

A result of '1' (one) means Full text search **is** installed on the SQL Server.

If it is not installed you'll need to rerun the SQL Server setup and add the Full Text Search feature.  Here's a good article that shows you how to [Verify & Install Full Text Search](http://sqlish.com/installing-full-text-search-on-sql-server/)

Answer (score 6):

You need to execute this system sproc to enable fulltext indexing:

```
--enable fulltext index
EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention which edition of SQL Server you're using, but if it's SQL Express, you need to make sure that you've downloaded and installed SQL Server 2008 with Advanced Services.  The "plain" SQL Server Express install doesn't include Full-Text Search (to keep the package size to a minimum).  View and download the various editions [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/).

If you're on a non-express version, you need to make sure that you've installed the Full-Text search feature - if you haven't, run the installer again and select "full text search" on the features page.

Answer (score 2):

I fix the problem by restarting SSMS 18.1

Comment: Stupidly enough, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you looking that its greyed out ? If its on a database you need to go to storage / full text catalogs in management studio to change full text settings in sql server 2008.

You can check its installed in the first place by going to services; by default it seems to be disabled after install. If its not installed you can change the installed components through add remove programs.

Answer (score 0):

Try by creating a new database, because I was also having the same problem. I just created a new database and happy to see that Full-text Index enabled.